# How do I update "on duplicate key" values using data from select before?

Tags: mysql, insert

```
INSERT INTO 
Terminal_Plataforma_Aprox (IDVersion, IDPlataforma, ParquePorcentual, ParqueActual, PorcentajeActual, Fecha) 
SELECT A.IDVersion, A.Plataforma, (SUM(A.Parque)/217958.260), SUM(A.Parque) AS SUMA, SUM(A.Porcentaje) AS PORCENTAJE, NOW() FROM 
Terminales_Parque_Porcentual A GROUP BY A.Plataforma, A.IDVersion 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ParqueActual = A.SUMA, PorcentajeActual=A.PORCENTAJE
```

I need to update values `ParqueActual` and `PorcentajeActual` with values from select before this: `SUM(A.Parque) AS SUMA -SUM(A.Porcentaje) AS PORCENTAJE`

I always have error maybe I can´t make by other way.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [**VALUES()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values) , for that replace your following line:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ParqueActual = A.SUMA, PorcentajeActual=A.PORCENTAJE
```

for this one:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ParqueActual = VALUES(SUM(Parque)), PorcentajeActual=VALUES(PORCENTAJE)
```

that should do it.

Comment: I change It but I get this error:  
`#1054 - Unknown column 'SUMA' in 'field list'`  

::MYSQL VERSION ::  
`Versión del servidor: 5.5.16`